# Is it possible to embed an executable inside a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, embed, executable

There are many programs which help me write more efficient code (NirCmd etc.), but they can't run properly if they aren't installed in the computer. So is there a way to, for example, in the temp folder, extract the program from a batch program and use it.

I tried reading the executables with a hex editor, putting the hex code into another file and saving it as an executable. But this failed. So, is there any way to efficiently store an executable inside a batch file, create it and then run it?

Comment: You can use a combination of Certutil and Makecab to accomplish this. This question has been covered on SO already as well.

Comment: I don't see the point of asking a question you've already got an answer for, especially one for which you'd already produced a code and posted externally prior to posing your question. This could effectively be deemed spam.

Comment: @Compo, sorry, I've seen people do this and I'm just trying to help. I guess I shouldn't do this anymore.

Comment: It wouldn't have appeared to have been so bad had you not changed somebody elses code and broken it in doing so. The end result being that the only useful part of your answer is the link to the original bhx site.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is one that I know of and works perfectly.

It is a program called bhx.exe ([link to its site here](http://consolesoft.com/p/bhx/index.html)).
It can also embed other file types.

The usage is quite simple:

1. (optional) Create a cabinet (.cab) file from the original .exe using this command: `makecab yourexe.exe yourexe.cab`. For better compression you can use the /D switch in this way: `makecab /D CompressionType=LZX yourexe.exe yourexe.cab`
2. `CD` to the directory bhx is in and do this: `bhx yourexe.cab`. Other switches are described in the website.

There you go, the mybin.cmd file is generated.

Comment: Kappa, the code you have posted on the external site is wrong!"